# Calculate min, max, count in linux file

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file on linux server that has data like :

```
a   22
a   10
a   17
a   51
a   33
b   51
b   47
c   33
```

I want a shell script or linux commands to find min, avg, 90%, max and count for each value in column 1.

Example:

```
for a min = 10, avg = 26, 90% = 33, max = 51, and count = 5.
```

Comment: Hint: you can start with `sort` shell command.

Comment: I have tried diffrent calls for each operation such as to find count :- `sort api_calls | uniq -c | sort -nr`. But I need a single command and script to do that.

Comment: awk might help here.  Read the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a version with even the 90% percentile using gawk.

The definition of percentile is that one given by
Wikipedia and called [Nearest rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile).

The function round can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Round-Function.html).

```
#!/bin/bash

gawk '
function round(x, ival, aval, fraction)
{
    ival = int(x)    # integer part, int() truncates

    # see if fractional part
    if (ival == x)   # no fraction
        return ival   # ensure no decimals

    if (x < 0) {
        aval = -x     # absolute value
        ival = int(aval)
        fraction = aval - ival
        if (fraction >= .5)
            return int(x) - 1   # -2.5 --> -3
        else
            return int(x)       # -2.3 --> -2
    } else {
        fraction = x - ival
        if (fraction >= .5)
            return ival + 1
        else
            return ival
    }
}
# the following block processes all the lines
# and populates counters and values
{
    if($1 in counters) {
        counters[$1]++;
    } else {
        counters[$1] = 1;
    }
    i = counters[$1];
    values[$1, i] = $2;
} END {
    for (c in counters) {
        delete tmp;
        min = values[c, 1];
        max = values[c, 1];
        sum = values[c, 1];
        tmp[1] = values[c, 1];
        for (i = 2; i <= counters[c]; i++) {
            if (values[c, i] < min) min = values[c, i];
            if (values[c, i] > max) max = values[c, i];
            sum += values[c, i];
            tmp[i] = values[c, i];
        }

        # The following 3 lines compute the percentile.
        n = asort(tmp, tmp_sorted);
        idx = round(0.9 * n + 0.5); # Nearest rank definition
        percentile = tmp_sorted[idx];

        # Output of the statistics for this group.  
        printf "for %s min = %d, avg = %f, 90 = %d,max = %d, count = %d\n", c, min, (sum / counters[c]), percentile, max, counters[c]; 
    }
}'
```

To run execute:

```
./stats.sh < input.txt
```

I am assuming that the above script is named stats.sh and your input is saved in input.txt.

The output is:

```
for a min = 10, avg = 26.600000, 90 = 51,max = 51, count = 5
for b min = 47, avg = 49.000000, 90 = 51,max = 51, count = 2
for c min = 33, avg = 33.000000, 90 = 33,max = 33, count = 1
```

Here the explanation:

counters is an associative array, the key is the value in column 1
and the value is the number of values found in the input for each
value in column 1.

values is a two dimensional (value_in_column_one, counter_per_value)
array that keeps all the values grouped by value in column one.

At the end of the script the outermost loop goes trough all the values
found in column 1. The innermost for loop analyses all the values belonging
to a particular value in column 1 and it computes all the statics.

Answer (score 0):

For lines starting with `a`, here's an `awk` script.

```
$ echo 'a 22
a 10
a 17
a 51
a 33
b 51
b 47
c 33' | awk 'BEGIN{n=0;s=0;};/^a/{n=n+1;s=s+$2;};END{print n;print s;print s/n;}'
5
133
26.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{min=$1} {sum+=$2; if(min>=$2) min=$2; if(max<$2) max=$2} 
     END{printf("max=%d,min=%d,count=%d,avg=%.2f\n", max, min, NR, (sum/NR))}' file
max=51,min=10,count=8,avg=33.00
```

**EDIT:**

```
awk '$1 != v {
   if (NR>1)
      printf("For %s max=%d,min=%d,count=%d,avg=%.2f\n", v, max, min, k, (sum/k));
   v=$1; 
   min=$2;
   k=sum=max=0
}
{
   k++;
   sum+=$2;
   if (min > $2)
      min=$2;
   if (max < $2)
      max=$2
}
END {
   printf("For %s max=%d,min=%d,count=%d,avg=%.2f\n", v, max, min, k, (sum/k))
}' < <(sort -n -k1,2 f)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
For a max=51,min=10,count=5,avg=26.60
For b max=51,min=47,count=2,avg=49.00
For c max=33,min=33,count=1,avg=33.00
```

Comment: It gives min, max, avg, count stats for complete file. But I need it individually for each string in column 1 i.e. for a, b and c

Comment: That script will be more involved, I will edit my answer in few minutes.